# How to publish a Chrome Web Store app to Apps Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Why is my app showing on Chrome Web Store and not Apps Marketplace, although I added the service "Google Apps Marketplace SDK" to the existing app?

What are the steps to publish an existing Chrome Web Store app to Apps Marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

The new Apps Marketplace is based on the Chrome Web Store. This is just like how Drive Apps work. The CWS is just the container and listing service - the apps are still installable by admins on every browser.

Comment: Ok, but how will admins see my app if it's not listed in the Apps Marketplace: https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace

Comment: In the admin console, there is a contextual Apps Marketplace widget where they can discover and install the new app.

Comment: The old Apps Marketplace will continue working for a while but you cannot create new listings.

Comment: Ok, then what should I do to have my existing CWS app listed in the contextual Apps Marketplace widget and visible to all admins, not only in my domain?