# What needs to be done to have our app listed in the new contextual Apps Marketplace widget?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

A few weeks ago, we completed the approval process to get our app listed in the [Google Apps Marketplace](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/). It does appear on that site and all is fine. However it is not listed in the contextual Apps Marketplace widget in the Google Apps admin console.

I've read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432112/how-to-publish-a-chrome-web-store-app-to-apps-marketplace) that since November 19th the Apps Marketplace has a new back-end based on the Chrome Web Store, and that only the apps added since then appear in the contextual widget.

So my question is: what will happen to the apps listed in the "old" Marketplace? Will they get automatically migrated to the new back-end at some point? Or do we need to start over the whole publishing process again using the new Marketplace SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will be launching an API in a few weeks to allow developers to automatically move the domains that installed the legacy (OAuth 1/OpenID) based apps to the new Chrome Web Store (and OAuth2) based Apps Marketplace.

In the mean time, the first step is to create a new listing using the GAM SDK following the steps in the docs so that new domains can install the modern app and then you can migrate the older domains when we launch the API.

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/

Comment: Ok, so there will be no migration of the listings themselves. That sucks. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Correct, we will provide API to migrate the install records, but you have to create a new listing. Agreed this is painful, but this will improve the future direction of this platform as this now will run on a shared infrastructure like Chrome Web Store.